# Fastest way to quickly execute an array of many  PHP pages?

Tags: php, jquery

What is the fastest way to execute many PHP pages. I will not need to see them (i.e. scrape or retain any information from any html that is output), but they need to load. The PHP code within each page needs to be executed.

I first started out doing `foreach (...){echo <iframe src=....` (*very ugly and took **very** long and very bad idea*)

Now I'm thinking to set a jquery timer to keep loading ajax requests and go through an array.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: pages or classes or custom functions? This one make sense at least

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you  doing it on the client or server (if client then PHP tag is not relevant as it has no bearing on possible answers).

Comment: @nickdos server side (preferably), but I'm also ok with jquery. I guess think of it like crawling except once the page is finished loading I don't need anything from it -- except that it loads and runs the commands in each php file.

Comment: @metal_fan they are essentially just php scripts, they don't produce any output.

Comment: Seems like the wrong tool for the job then. Why not use a shell script to process the jobs?

Comment: Absolutely down for that as well. I should have mentioned that the data is compiled from a mysql database, and i happen to have it in a php array

Comment: @iight it's not jquery timer, but javascript one. If they don't have to produce any output then you use them as some kinda libraries, that is you include some chunks of code you need to work with. So what's your problem here? By the way it's not that slow as you might think.

Comment: I betcha you won't get clear answer until you ask proper question. Your question isn't clear to us

Comment: @metal_fan I couldn't agree more with you haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threading is going to let you call URL's as fast as possible as you can have multiple loading at the exact same time. PHP doesn't really have good support for multi-threading but we can have it do multi-processing. This will allow you to kick off a URL request and immediately kick off more without waiting for any of the pages to load.

The following code is an example of how to accomplish this using wget. This will be fast but does have the downside of not letting you know about a success or failure.

```
<?php
foreach($pages as $page){
    exec('/usr/bin/wget '.$page.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
}
?>
```

This could be taken a step further to call your own php script instead of wget. In which case your program can log the urls that failed to load.

So a complete example could be something like the following:

**run.php**

```
<?php
foreach($pages as $page){
    exec('loadPage.php '.$page.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
}
?>
```

**loadPage.php**

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($argv[1]);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpdCode != '200'){
    $fp = fopen('error.log', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, 'The URL '.$url.' had an issue. It returned a '.$httpCode.' error.');
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: There're two mistakes (at least): 1) PHP isn't like Python or JavaScript. To iterate over array(or objects) we use `foreach` instead of `for ... in`. 2) The function `exec()` does not exist in PHP.

Comment: The for() was a typo as I started with for($i=0;i<$pages;$i++) but switched it at last minute. [Exec()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) most definitely does exist in PHP.

Comment: @Brett I will try this out. it sounds like a perfect answer for what I am trying to do. I can easily verify whether it worked or not using mysql. In fact it'll be easier than some sort of text output. Thank you! I'll let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
<?php

$pages = array();

$pages[] = 'page1.php';
$pages[] = 'page2.php';
$pages[] = 'page3.php';
$pages[] = 'page4.php';
$pages[] = 'page5.php';

foreach($pages as $page):
    include $page;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: It's better to `require()` rather than `include()` because we have no idea if that inclusion would fail.

Answer (score 1):

well although there will be minimal difference from my understanding foreach is the slowest type of loop. Your real issue is the iframe they are notoriously slow. what you should be doing is an include(); or require(); or even require_once();

```
$pages = array();
$pages[] = "Page1.php";
$pages[] = "Page2.php";
$pages[] = "Page3.php";
foreach($pages as $page)
{
require($page);
}
```

Avoid using iframes as I believe they are actually planned to have support for them dropped.
if you need them to appear a certain was or style just use CSS to position them how  you had when you were using an iframe but use a div in its place.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need any of the html ever rendered in the browser, only executed.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient thing to do by far is thread it ...

http://pthreads.org

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads ( does not contain latest release, git if you can )

I think it's highly likely that the only reason the code is contained in several pages ( which I assume are local ) is because this was the only way to achieve concurrency in PHP ... if that's correct then you should most likely rewrite the code as you do not require your server for concurrency anymore. Even if they are external sites on different physical machines, threading the requests is the thing to do ... you can even

http://pthreads.org/pool.php

and it's soooooo easy

http://pthreads.org/pool.phps